# Calling fgets() on popen() of 'ssh' is flushing the beginning of stdin of the calling process (ptty issue)

Tags: ssh, stdin, popen, fgets, pty

I have now whittled this down to a minimal test case.  Thus far I have been able to determine that this is an issue related to pseudo-terminals which come about with the pipe of ssh.  Adding the '-t -t' to the ssh call improved things, in that now, it takes a second call to fgets() to cause the issue.  I suspect that the stderr output of the ssh command somehow works into the issue, for now I have redirected stderr to stdout in the ssh code to execute.  I do wonder if the "tcgetattr: Invalid argument" error is part of the problem, but am not sure how to get rid of that.  It seems to come from the -t -t being present.  I believe the -t -t is moving in the right direction, but I have to set up the pseudo terminal for stderr somehow and perhaps the test will work properly?

The Makefile:

```
test:
    gcc -g -DBUILD_MACHINE='"$(shell hostname)"' -c -o test.o test.c
    gcc -g -o test test.o

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf test.o test
```

The test.c source file:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  const unsigned int bufSize = 32;
  char buf1[bufSize];
  char buf2[bufSize];
  int ssh = argv[1][0] == 'y';
  const char *cmd = ssh ? "ssh -t -t " BUILD_MACHINE " \"ls\" 2>&1" : "ls";

  FILE *fPtr = popen(cmd, "r");

  if (fPtr == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Unable to spawn command.\n");
        perror("popen(3)");
        exit(1);
  }
  printf("Command: %s\n", cmd);
  if (feof(fPtr) == 0 && fgets(buf2, bufSize, fPtr) != NULL) {
    printf("First result: %s\n", buf2);
    if (feof(fPtr) == 0 && fgets(buf2, bufSize, fPtr) != NULL) {
      printf("Second result: %s\n", buf2);
      int nRead = read(fileno(stdin), buf1, bufSize);

      if (nRead == 0) {
        printf("???? popen() of ssh consumed the beginning of stdin ????\n");
      } else if (nRead > 0) {
        if (strncmp("The quick brown fox jumped", buf1, 26) != 0) {
          printf("??? Failed ???\n");
        } else {
          printf("!!!!!!!   Without ssh popen() did not consume stdin   !!!!!!!\n");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This shows it running the passing way:

```
> echo "The quick brown fox jumped" | ./test n
Command: ls
First result: ARCH.linux_26_i86

Second result: Makefile

!!!!!!!   Without ssh popen() did not consume stdin   !!!!!!!
```

This shows it running the failing way:

```
> echo "The quick brown fox jumped" | ./test y
Command: ssh -t -t hostname "ls" 2>&1
First result: tcgetattr: Invalid argument

Second result: %backup%~              gmon.out

???? popen() of ssh consumed the beginning of stdin ????
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I have got this working finally.  The secret was to supply /dev/null as the input to my ssh command as follows from the test case above:

```
      const char *cmd
        = ssh ? "ssh -t -t " BUILD_MACHINE " \"ls\" 2>&1 < /dev/null" : "ls";
```

However, while the code works correctly, I get a nasty message which apparently I can ignore for my purposes (although I'd like to make the message go away):

```
tcgetattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Comment: try piping the output TO /dev/null instead of FROM it.